# Is crafting broken or intentionally nerfed?

Tags: the-division

I've been crafting some guns lately, and no matter how hard I try, they are 500-1000 DMG below the *lower* bound of the blue print displayed range. Seems to have happened after the update.

Is it yet another Ubi bug, or is it intentional nerf to crafting?

Comment: This feels more like a forum post than a question with a specific answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug, i had the exact same problem, after some days the minimum and maximum value fell down and was at its original state.

There is not really something you can do about that, sometimes just switching gear or adding mods helps.

There is also a bug where the Primary DPS is old and when you hover over your gear it is original, in that case you just have to click at one of your gear pieces and the Primary DPS refreshes itself.

Comment: _"after some days the minimum and maximum value fell down and was at its original state"_ — you mean the value displayed on the blueprint, right?

Comment: Yes i mean the value on the blueprint @vartec